# PHP DOMDocument GetElementsByTagName Not Finding Elements

Tags: php, dom, metadata

I have an HTML page containing alot of meta tags and I want to parse them to find certain ones. Here is the code I am using, but it's not picking up any of the tags.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;  
$dom->loadHtml($contents);  
$metaChildren = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');  
var_dump($metaChildren);
```

Here is a snippet of the HTML I am using (I replaced the arrow with a brace):

```
[meta name="GZPlatform" content=" pc"]  
[meta name="GZFeatured" content=" Gone Gold"]  
[meta name="GZHeadline" content=" pc"]  
[meta name="GZP_ID" content=" pc 21153"]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you are trying to match.  I wonder if you have a name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the tags aren't being matched? What is the output of `var_dump`? What value do you get when you use `var_dump($metaChildren->length)`? Your code seems to work here:

```
<?
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('test.html');
$metaChildren = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ($i = 0; $i < $metaChildren->length; $i++) {
  $el = $metaChildren->item($i);
  print $el->getAttribute('name') . '=' . $el->getAttribute('content') . "\n";
}
?>
```

Gives output:

```
GZPlatform= pc
GZFeatured= Gone Gold
GZHeadline= pc
GZP_ID= pc 21153
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the HTML is not valid and that the `$dom->loadHtml` call is failing. I believe that call returns true|false. So maybe something like this:

```
if($dom->loadHtml($contents)){
    $metaChildren = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
}else{
    //handle properly
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that it had to be valid html

Comment: actually, looked at the documentation, you are right. i'm used to using XML parsers. in either case though, it's a good idea to check that the load was successful before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

COuld it be that the parser expects you to close the meta tags?

```
<meta name="name" />
```

or

```
<meta name="name"></meta>
```