# get all <meta property > using php

Tags: php

How do I extract the "content" values of a  from the view source

I have used CURL to get the source of the page but after that I'm not able to identify the following:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Zoe&#39;s big surprise">
<meta property="og:description" content=" ">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PNyMlswZb-I/hqdefault.jpg">
```

basically I need to capture all the above parameters in an array and use them.
I have tried the following after curl

```
    //parsing begins here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($data);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

    //get and display what you need:
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta'); --This line is not able to fetch any <meta> content>
```

Thanks

Comment: How does the whole source look like?

Comment: its the complete HTML code ...like the view source kind

Comment: I know what it is... I meant paste it here!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument GetElementsByTagName Not Finding Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765968/php-domdocument-getelementsbytagname-not-finding-elements) ?

Comment: Furthermore: Is property a valid attribute for the meta tag? Didn't use it in a veeeery long time, maybe try name instead?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
$html = '<meta property="og:title" content="Zoe&#39;s big surprise">
<meta property="og:description" content=" ">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PNyMlswZb-I/hqdefault.jpg">';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta ) { 
   $metaData[] = array(
        'property' => $meta->getAttribute('property'),
        'content' => $meta->getAttribute('content')
    );
}

print_r( $metaData );
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [property] => og:title
            [content] => Zoe's big surprise
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [property] => og:description
            [content] =>  
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [property] => og:type
            [content] => video
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [property] => og:image
            [content] => http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/PNyMlswZb-I/hqdefault.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: I have tried the above it does not fetch anything..the code i had written is identical  to what you have used..thanks anyways

Comment: I haven't written the output manually, i just ran the code i wrote on my server and copy/pasted what i saw as output. So i am pretty sure this works as it is. There must be a problem with your method of capturing $data to load in DOMDocument.

Comment: this is my code                                                $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML($data);$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');  for ($l = 0; $l < $metas->length; $l++)
  {
   $meta = $metas->item($l);
   if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
    {
     $urlDet['src'][$firstSeti] = $meta->getAttribute('content');}}

Comment: I got the error in my code -While getting the content of the webpage , i was extracting the "text/html" content . I changed that to "text" alone . and it worked. after noticing the webpage extract i noticed that when extract is made with "text/html" it omits the meta tags. thanks